# Google Dev Tools conflicting dimensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

In the image you'll see that next to the checkmark and "screen" **dev tools shows that the dimensions are 320x568 however** underneath that, the guides are showing that *the width is almost 950 and length is well beyond 1500.* Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a zoom of 0.3, which effectively shrinks your page size by 3.33x. Try resetting your zoom to 1.

Comment: ahh, that fixes the width issue. however, to get to the far right of my website I have to side scroll within the simulated device border. it's showing still that the far right of my website is at about 975. does that make sense? i can edit the question and add the new screen shots of what I mean if it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, it does make sense. The default layout width in Chrome is 980px. If you want your page to fit the width of your device screen (i.e. make it phone-friendly :)), use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` (refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)).

Comment: Wonderful, thanks so much for your help. Worked like a charm. :-)